# NumbaPro JIT a class constructor

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am looking for a way to use JIT for a python class constructor like so:

```
import numpy as np
from numbapro import jit, autojit
from time import time

class Test(object):
    @jit((float, float, float), target="cpu")
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z

    @autojit
    def runTest(self):
        N = 1000000
        self._z = 0
        for i in xrange(N):
            self._z = self._z + np.sin(i)

        return self._z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Test(4,5,6)

    start_time = time()
    z = a.runTest()
    end_time = time() # Get the CPU end time
    print("Math Time: {0} s".format(end_time - start_time))
    print z
```

However, it seem that I have to give a type for the `self`, which I do not know how to achieve.
Maybe someone knows how to get around this?

Thanks in advance
Andi

Comment: The decorator `@jit@jit` on line 6 is a typo, or is it correct?

Comment: Absolutely a typo! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for "jitting" classes was dropped from numba from version 0.12: [here is the Github issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/398). There used to be [support for classes in Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.6/doc/extension_types.html), called 'extension types' , but nowadays all related examples do not work, giving:  `TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable` if executed with the current release (0.17).

I would therefore *strongly* suggest you move the `runTest` functionality to its own function, and that you use [a tuple](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/pysupported.html#tuple) or [a numpy array](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/numpysupported.html) to pass in data to that function, because those mechanisms are supported.  Otherwise, you are stuck to using older versions of numba.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


@jit(float(float))
def runTest(z):
    N = 1000000
    z = 0
    for i in xrange(N):
        z = z + np.sin(i)
    return z


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Test(4,5,6)

    start_time = time()
    z = runTest(a.z)
    end_time = time() # Get the CPU end time
    print("Math Time: {0} s".format(end_time - start_time))
    print z
```

Comment: Yes this works! You can even include a helper function within the class and use autojit. Therefore I assume there has to be the option to go with jit as well. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @andi please accept the answer if it solves your problem. It can help others who find this question later on.

Comment: It does not. This is really not the way it should be solved in my point of view. It does not JIT a member function.

Comment: @andi : it seems I misunderstood your previous comment.  For my understanding: why do you need the `runTest` function to be a part of a class?  All examples in the current documentation JIT a function, not a class method.

Comment: I know that. This is why I was asking in the first place :(      Because I want to accelerate some functions of a class I have written and really do not want to exclude the functions from the class. This would not be good programming in my opinion.

Comment: @andi : I made a bit more of research and it seems extension types are not supported anymore :(  You can read my edited answer; otherwise, do not think that having methods outside of classes is always 'bad programming'.   It can be, yes; but here it seems the library authors' design.

Comment: Thanks for your time!